# Passing data between activities problems

Tags: android, android-studio

In my project, I am using the volley library to get data, and based on this data I will be adding buttons, the buttons are displayed correctly but the problem is that opening another activity is not working:

```
RequestQueue requestQueue;
TextView txt;
final int MY_REQ_CODE = 12345;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_categories);

    final GridLayout layout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getApplicationContext());

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "url", null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonanswer = response.getJSONObject("answer");
                        final String[] name=new String[9];

                        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

                        JSONArray result = jsonanswer.getJSONArray("result");

                        for (int i=0;i<jsonArrayresult.length();i++){
                            JSONObject objresp = result.getJSONObject(i);

                            String name= objresp.getString("name");

                            name[i] = name;
                        }

                        for (int i=0;i<titles.length;i++){
                            Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());

                            btn.setText(titles[i]);

                            layout.addView(btn);

                            btn.setOnClickListener(getProducts);
                            btn.setTag(titles[i]);
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("VOLLEY", "ERROR");
                }
            }
    );

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}

View.OnClickListener getProducts = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Object tag = v.getTag();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), otherActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("name", tag.toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == MY_REQ_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //??

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Result canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And my second activity is:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_products_list);

    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    finish();

    final Intent intent = getIntent();

    final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

    Bundle title = intent.getExtras();
    if (title != null) {
        str = title.getString("title");
    }

    txt.setText(str);

}
```

Comment: So what's going wrong, then? What is it that you are trying to accomplish that isn't happening? What does "not working" mean? Is `onClick()` not getting called?

Comment: I just tried and the onClick method is getting called but opening another activity is not working

Comment: I've updated my question @NoChinDeluxe

Answer (score 1):

When moving between your internal activities you should use [startActivity(intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) method and not startActivityForResult.

Change:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, MY_REQ_CODE);
```

To:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

**UPDATE:**
From what I can see you also create a new button named btn but you assing the listener to other button. I don't see where you create the **btncategorie** button, it should be:

```
Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());
btn.setText(titles[i]);
btn.setOnClickListener(getProducts);
btn.setTag(titles[i]);
layout.addView(btn);
```

Comment: Can you update your main question and include the entire activity class ?

Comment: I'm sorry I've changed some data to display my class here and forgot to change those btnCategorie.